# C# Passing array of string element into a Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, task

Trying to pass an element of an array of strings into a function which is being called in a Task.Run. Anyone know what is the error here?

The code here doesn't work, it behaves as if ProcessElem never gets called.

```
string[] arr = message.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] != "") {
       var t = Task.Run(() => this.ProcessElem(arr[i]));
    }
 }
```

However the code below works

```
string[] arr = message.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] != "") {
       var tmp = arr[i];
       var t = Task.Run(() => this.ProcessElem(tmp));
    }
 }
```

I'm very new to how C# does things, but it seems like both patterns are unsafe because the function that calls Task.Run() might return before the ProcessElem function executes, and if the strings are pass by reference then they will be destroyed before ProcessElem is called.

If this is the case, what would be the best way to pass the string into ProcessElem?

Also, why doesn't the first version actually "call" ProcessElem? I have a print statement at the top of ProcessElem and it only gets printed @ the second version.

Comment: What's a "print statement"? Can you show us `ProcessElem' or a condensed version that exhibits the problem. And, what kind if environment are you running in WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, a console app...?

Comment: It is a console app. ProcessElem simply prints the string passed into it. public void ProcessElem(string str) { Console.WriteLine(str);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to [captured variables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c/).

```
Task.Run(() => this.ProcessElem(arr[i]))
```

This essentially means:

1. Take my lambda action: `() => this.ProcessElem(arr[i])`
2. Run it after you've found/created a thread to do so. *i.e.* *some time later*.

However, there's only one variable involved, `i`, and that's defined outside your lambda action's scope, it's not being copied, the *same* variable is just being *captured* and referenced.

By the time that thread gets around to executing, the value of `i` has most likely changed. Usually, the loop finishes *before* the threads perform their work.

That means that by that time, `i` equals `arr.Length` and all threads try to access `arr[arr.length]` which obviously results in an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

When you do `var tmp = arr[i];`, you are creating a fresh variable per loop iteration, copying the loop variable and capturing that copy in your lambda, which is why it works.

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem is how the actual "coroutines" work in C#

`i` is not passed as the current value but rather as `ref i` which means that your `Action` always will receive the current `i` value when it gets executed.

Chances are, you run this code and the Tasks are not executed in parallel. That means, the specific task executed gets the current value of `i` which, in most simple cases, will be as provided as exit condition: `arr.Length + 1`

to proof:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] != "")
    {
        var j = i;
        var t = Task.Run(() => ProcessElem(arr[j]));
        tasklist.Add(t);
    }
}
```

will work perfectly fine (unless you have some problems in your `ProcessElem` method :P)

in regards of string-destruction, unless you got some object that implements `IDisposable`, you should be fine with passing it into some lambda.
It will exist, until the actual lambda got deleted (as it will retain some reference to the object eg. in this case `arr`)

Comment: So, when I do 
Task.Run(() => this.ProcessElem(arr[i])), the value of 'i' passed in by reference, thus it is possible that its value is arr.Length (because coroutines could all run in the same thread), which would be an index out of bounds? I understand how co-routines work, but intuitively I thought the value of arr[i] was what is being passed into ProcessElem, (evaluated when the task ProcessElem is queued to the ThreadPool). Not a reference to i, that will then be used to calculate the value of arr[i]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an age old issue, its how lamdas work, and its very well documented.

However, assuming you are just creating and awaiting a bunch of tasks, then save your self code, hassle, and task creation and just use *TPL* `Parallel.For` or `AsParallel`

```
Parallel.For(0, arr.Length, (i) => ProcessElem(arr[i]));
```

Or

```
arr.AsParallel().ForAll(ProcessElem);
```

Or if you really don't want empty strings

```
arr.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
   .AsParallel()
   .ForAll(ProcessElem);
```